# OpenShift V3 Generic WebHook Tag

Tags: git, docker, tags, push, openshift

I'm trying to understand how to provide a Docker image tag that will be included with the image pushed to my private Docker registry when a webhook call is made to OpenShift v3.  The overall process of having Git commits initiate the build, image, and registry push are all fine.  They are initiated by the webhook I perform post-Git-commit, via a cURL command.

I'm just unsure of how to append the Docker image tag in the webhook so that OpenShift picks it up and uses it upon pushing to the local registry.  Otherwise I'm stuck with a bunch of images that all share the same tag/latest.

The closest I've seen in the OpenShift documentation is the following.  I'm not even sure if it's relevant to what I'm trying to do or not.

```
{
  type: 'git',
  git: {
    uri: '<url to git repository>',
    ref: '<optional git reference>',
    commit: '<commit hash identifying a specific git commit>',
    author: {
      name: '<author name>',
      email: '<author e-mail>',
    },
    committer: {
      name: '<committer name>',
      email: '<committer e-mail>',
    },
    message: '<commit message>'
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not possible today to pass the output image destination through to the build, although it's probably possible to add.  There's a minor security risk to it where it could be abused (you could force push somewhere else).  Most of these scenarios are things we handle from the integrated registry today, so it just hasn't come up yet to allow that passthrough

Comment: @Clayton, thanks for the reply.  So to be clear, there's no way to have the Docker image tagged during it's build when being performed by OpenShift upon webhook call, and/or when it's automatically pushed to the integrated registry?  Wouldn't this restrict automatic docker image builds to something like `namespace/image:latest` instead of, say, `namespace/image:1.0.1`?

Comment: ^ This is during the S2I process.

Comment: The solution here was not to use the webhook at all.  Instead, use the oc command to perform a `start-build`, use the `--follow --wait` parameters to wait until the build is completed.  We can also pass additional variables that we may need in the image.

`oc start-build <app> --env=<some key> <some value> --follow --wait`

Then use oc again to tag the image stream as needed.

`oc tag <project>/<image_name>:latest <project>/<image_name>:<version_number>`